# How to time the time it takes to send something from a server to a browser and reverse

Tags: ajax, node.js, http, websocket, latency

I want time how long it takes to send a few things from the browser to a server and the reverse (but not round trip). I know there are various timings available for each, but the only thing that I think would work is a very accurate system time for both (they are both local). Something like the browser's performance.now() would be perfect but I don't know how to compare it with the server side. I'm using node as the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many profilers for nodejs that time the execution of blocks of your choice.

Example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exectimer

https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/profiler